# How do i grab next portion of string - java?

Tags: java, string, integer, distinct

I'm currently writing a distinct number program, and have to go by the book. The user inputs a String value of digits.. in example "65 3 4 9". I need to grab each of those digits, convert them to an integer, and place the integer in an array. HOWEVER, what if multiple chars will equal one integer? (so for the above example the array at index 0 == 65). In previous programs I've used charAt(loop variable).. but am not certain that is what I need in this situation.

Can any of you give me a hint? Something tells me I've done this before but am drawing a blank. Thanks.

Comment: Initialize a `Scanner` with your `String` for example `new Scanner("65 3 4 9")`, and then use `Scanner#nextInt()`.

Comment: Check out the `split()` method of the `String` class. Hint: You can split on an empty space `myString.split(" ")` to get an array of Strings where each entry is a String representation of your numbers above, then you just need to parse int (`Integer.parseInt(...)`)

Comment: Ok, so use one string to retrieve user input, and then break it into multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

Like 'Kon' said in the comments,

```
String myString = "65 3 4 9" 
String[] stringArray = myString.split(" "); 
int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length -1 ; i++){
 intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]); 
}
```

This should help